# How to create fade in/ fade out effects for audio to a given value (other than 100%) using ffmpeg and python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I would like to create fade in/ fade out effects to values other than 100% of volume and 0% of volume. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To create a afade filter string to pass to ffmpeg this helper function can be used:

```
def create_afade_arg(is_in, start, end, fade_to_percent):
    d = 100*(end-start)/(100-fade_to_percent)

    cmd = [f"afade=enable='between(t,{str(start)},{str(end)})':t="]

    if is_in:
        cmd.append("in")
        start = end - d
    else:
        cmd.append("out")

    cmd.append(f":st={start}:d={d}")

    return ''.join(cmd)
```

You can then use it in "-filter_complex" for example, like this:

```
fade_t = 2 # duration of fade in seconds
fade_to_percent = 10 # target percent of volume to fade to

afade_arg = create_afade_arg( True, pos, pos+fade_t, fade_to_percent)
afade_str = ','.join(afade_arg)
```

... and passed to ffmpeg like this:

```
exit_code = subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "input.mp3", "-filter_complex", "[in]" + afade_str + "[out]" ,"-map", "[out]", "out.mp3"])
```

Comment: `afade_str` ends up being `a,f,a,d,e,=,e,n,a,b,l,e,=,',b,e,t,w,e,e,n,(,t,,,0,.,1,,,2,.,1,),',:,t,=,i,n,:,s,t,=,-,0,.,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,:,d,=,2,.,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3`. Why is it separated with so many commas? I'm confused, this doesn't look right.

Comment: Make sure the 'cmd' is an array. I am not sure why it wouldn't be at your end but just check.